# Inconsistent HTTPResponse handling

Tags: web-access

It seems that sources of `URL*` related features are not initialized properly which leads to problems in many cases.

Please follow those steps to reproduce the problem:

- Let's deploy a test api:

  ```
  api = First @ CloudDeploy @ Delayed @ HTTPErrorResponse[404]
  ```
- Check:

  ```
  URLRead[api]
  ```

  > [image]

  So far so good
- Copy `api` url string and try

  ```
    URLRead["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/...."]
  ```

  Should return 404, nothing unexpected.
- Now `Quit[]` the Kernel and run the manual check again:

  ```
    URLRead["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/...."]
  ```

  > [image]

What?

What is more interesting, deploy another `api` and run manual test for the **old url**, now it works again...

How to classify this feature? What to call to have stuff initialized/loaded properly?

> [CASE:3855442] was created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quick explanation:** Thanks to WRI Support reply we can understand why this happens:

- the cloud object has default private privileges
- so in new session `URLRead` will be redirected to cloud login page, correctly returning 200

**Further doubts:** This makes things clearer but I still believe the behavior isn't entirely consistent. Here is why:

- I have cloud credentials cached by 'Remember Me' checkbox
- Calling cloud object specified by plain url string works, once we are logged in, and does not require any addition to `URLRead` in order to resolve the authorization

So I'd expect it to always work or to have 'Remember Me' well documented. E.g. when exactly credentials are restored in a new session.

WRI Support agrees:

> [..] I understand the way that Mathematica handles the saved Wolfram Cloud credentials is complex and needs further clarification. I have forwarded your suggestion to the appropriate people in our development group. [...]

**What to do to not face the issue?**

Using `CloudObject` as a wrapper for cloud links reminds Mathematica that credentials are needed and it will work even after `Quit[]`.

```
api = First @ CloudDeploy @ Delayed @ HTTPErrorResponse[404]
```

> ```
>  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/..."
> ```

```
Quit[];
```

```
URLRead["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/..."]

(*200*)

URLRead[CloudObject @ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/..."]

(*404*)
```