# Inconsistent Authorization Dialog (401) handling

Tags: bugs, front-end, options, web-access, dialog-window

**Bug introduced in V11 and fixed in 11.3**

> [CASE:3855554] was created
>
> [...] It does appear that the URLRead is not behaving correctly. I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

---

This issue is similar to one from a recent report:

[Inconsistent HTTPResponse handling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139536/5478)

but I decided to post a separate question because I have a fix for this one and not for the linked one.

- So, let's call where we should not:

  ```
  URLRead["https://httpbin.org/status/401", Interactive -> False]
  ```

  > [image]

  The `Interactive -> False` option prevents a native authentication dialog from poping up. More in: [How to omit the authentification dialog during URLRead?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129051/5478)
- now please `Quit[]`
- run the code from above again

  The dialog pops up anyway.

  [image]

Have I missed something? Is this a bug?

Comment: It's get more serious in version 11.1.The windows will pup up numerous times.And the option of `Interactive` or `"DisplayProxyDialog"` don't take even little effect anymore,which make `URLRead` almost disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that some functions are not initialized correctly and options are not passed around as they should. Mentioning `URLFetch`, which is probably used internally, fixes that

```
 Quit[]
```

```
URLFetch; URLRead["https://httpbin.org/status/401", Interactive -> False]
```

Comment: `URLFetch` is indeed used internally. It's what `URLRead` uses to do the proper call (I've spent too much time digging through the `PrintDefs` recently). Formats an `HTTPRequest` (this can actually be important) then passes the parameters to `URLFetch` and returns the `HTTPResponse` (then `URLFetch` goes down, on a Mac, to `CURLLink` which is just a `LibraryLink` style connection to curl).